# Can the Brace Matching colors be customized in F#?

Tags: f#, visual-studio-2012

In Visual Studio 2012 RC with the Dark color theme, the C# editor honors the color settings `Brace Matching (Highlight)` and `Brace Matching (Rectangle)` but the F# editor does not. As a result, the matching-braces highlight in the F# editor is a nearly-invisible slightly lighter shade of black.

Does anyone know of a workaround to make the F# brace-matching highlight... visible?

Comment: I don't know of anything. Does changing the background color help?

Comment: Whitespace is much more important than braces in F#.  Why are you looking at braces?  Do you have a specific example of code where that's even interesting?

Comment: I am pretty sure we noticed this color bug and have it fixed for the final release (trying to recall from memory).

Comment: @GregC - since you asked, what I was doing was writing unit tests for a DSL, which meant manually writing out deeply nested discriminated union hierarchies as my expected value from the parser. It's pretty hard to do that without a fair amount of nested parens, even in F#.

Answer (score 1):

I remember Brian McNamara's work for VS2010...  Does [this plug-in](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0713522e-27e6-463f-830a-cb8f08e467c4/) work in VS2012?

This comes up on the first page of  Extension Manager -> Online Gallery when searching for FSharp.

Comment: No, I think it may allow an install on VS2012, but is broken on 2012.  I need to update it.